# Need explanation on output of this C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define F1(X) ((X > 0) ? X : -(X))
#define F2(X) (X > 0) ? X : -X

int main(){
    int a=5, b=10;
    printf("F1=%d, F2=%d\n", F1(a-b), F2(a-b));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is: `F1=5, F2=-15`

Of course, I'd think that the output of F1 and F2 should be the same. What do the parentheses have anything to do with the output?

Comment: Difference between a function and text substitution.  Very instructive.

Comment: Macros are textually substituted, do the substitution yourself, and you'll see why the parentheses have an influence.

Comment: `-(5 - 10)` versus `-5 - 10`.

Comment: @stark What a wonderfully informative answer...

Comment: It's not an answer, it is a comment. You can answer this yourself if you just realize that macros is nothing but text replacement. Any beginner level C book addresses the macro parenthesis issue, so I would suggest reading one. After that, the answer is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This program is a simple demonstration of why you always need to parenthesize macro parameters when you use them in expressions. It also illustrates a broader point of why you need to be very careful with macros in general.

> I'd think that the output of F1 and F2 should be the same

Had `F1` and `F2` been functions, not macros, the output would indeed be the same. However, macros are simple textual substitutions, so the two expressions that you get with and without parenthesizing of `X` are different:

F1:

```
((a-b > 0) ? a-b : -(a-b))
```

F2:

```
(a-b > 0) ? a-b : -a-b
```

Note that due to lack of parentheses `F2` applies unary minus to `a`, not to `(a-b)`.

This remains a relatively simple use of macros. Imagine the problems you would get in case when `X` is substituted for an expression with side effects, as in `F2(a++, b--)`.

Answer (score 1):

While playing with MACRO be careful of parenthesis`()`. After macro replacement it looks like this

```
 printf("F1=%d, F2=%d\n", ((a-b > 0) ? a-b : -(a-b)), (a-b > 0) ? a-b : -a-b);
```

Now calculate.

```
F1 => ((a-b > 0) ? a-b : -(a-b))
   => ((5-10 >0) ? 5-10 : -(5-10))
   => ((-5>0 ) false so it prints -(5-10) which is 5
```

and

```
  F2 => (a-b > 0) ? a-b : -a-b
     => (5-10 >0) ? 5-19 : -5-10
     => -5>0 false so it prints -15
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be careful with macros :

```
F1(a-b), F2(a-b)
```

turns to :

```
#define F1(X) ((X > 0) ? X : -(X))
#define F2(X) (X > 0) ? X : -X

int main(){
    int a=5, b=10;
    printf("F1=%d, F2=%d\n", 
                  ((a-b > 0) ? a-b : -(a-b)),
                  (a-b > 0) ? a-b : -a-b ); // < see here
    return 0;
}
```

in macros if you expect expression as param you should put them in parentheses *(**exp**)*